# Animating text in run tool window

Tags: npm, phpstorm, webstorm, ava

I'm using PhpStorm with a Laravel project and have set up a few basic JS tests using AVA.

They all work fine when I run them in the command line. e.g.:

**example.text.js**

```
import test from 'ava';
test('just a mockup', async (t) => {
      let i = 1;
      t.is(1,i);
});
```

If I run this in the terminal I get:

> npm run ava src/example.test.js
>
> ava [...]
>
> ava "src/example.test.js"
>
> 1 passed

However if I setup a run configuration and run it via the run window of PhpStorm I get:

> npm run ava src/example.test.js
>
> ava [...]
>
> ava "src/example.test.js"
>
> ⠋
>   ⠙
>   ⠹
>   ⠸
>   ⠼
>   ⠴
>   ⠦
>   ⠧
>   ⠧ just a mockup…
>
> 1 passed 
>   ⠇ just a mockup…
>
> 1 passed
>    1 passed

Which is the entire text "animation".

It's not really a problem but it's just annoying when there's many tests since you have to plow through all that junk to get to the actual meaningful information.

Is there any way to get the run window to animate the text?

**Update**

In case it helps anyone, I'm moving the comment conversation here:

There are 2 separate bug reports/feature requests in webstorm

1. [WEB-19849 Support ANSI commands to show progress correctly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19849) to allow ANSI commands in general (which is how the animations are achieved)
2. [WEB-21788 Support ava test runner](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19849) to allow the Webstom test interface for ava tests

In addition as a temporary solution for myself using the tap output (--tap) in my run configuration which looks a bit nicer.

Comment: Your question subject/summary does not seem to match the actual question body...

Comment: @LazyOne I seem to have used the title that was in a previous draft without noticing. Sorry about that

Comment: 1) Added `webstorm` tag as it's more of a JavaScript question (so it's more "close" to WebStorm product) -- that's only to make this question a bit more visible to the right people (who may not use PhpStorm). 2) About actual issue -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19849 (try asking about possible solution/progress there) 3) Actual ticket to have native support of AVA Test Runner -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21788

Comment: @LazyOne That first link is exactly the problem thanks. I've voted for it but it seems like there's not much interest so I guess no luck there.

Comment: Came across this thread while looking for options to turn off the command line animation. Future viewers: Please post links to solutions to disable the text animation.